# SQL Update latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue with an SQL update query:

```
UPDATE tblcurr
SET USD = 1 
Order by Date1 Desc 
limit 1
```

I would like the query to only update the record with the latest date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374015)**

```
UPDATE tblcurr 
SET USD = 1 
WHERE Date1 = (SELECT MAX(Date1) FROM tblcurr)
```

It may update multiple records if they have the same max Date1

Answer (score 1):

as @lad2025 already mentioned that `It may update multiple records if they have the same max Date1`

if you want to update only one record then you can try using [**ROW_NUMBER** ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Date1 desc)as rn
from tblcurr)
update cte set USD=1 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
UPDATE tblcurr
SET USD = 1 
where Date1 = MAX(Date1)
```

Comment: Nice try  ;)`An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

Comment: may be this may work `UPDATE tblcurr 
SET USD = 1 
WHERE Date1 = (SELECT MAX(Date1) FROM tblcurr limit1)`